# Applications missing in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome, menu

My applications are not showing in the menu when I press the <kbd>super</kbd> (windows) key. It says "Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search.", and I haven't searched for anything.  Here is the image of the screenshot I took of the menu:
[image: Missing applications]

Comment: Looks more like Unity than GNOME. For example, the close-minimize-maximize buttons are at left, not right.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot it seems, [contrary to what you think](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1186261/1), you have logged in to a *Unity* session, *not* a GNOME session.

Assuming you actually have GNOME desktop and GDM installed, there should be a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the "sign in" button at the login screen. Click it and select *GNOME* or *Ubuntu* or something similar instead of anything mentioning Unity.

Answer (score 1):

## UBUNTU 19.10 application menu empty after upgrade caused by installed extension incompatible with the new gnome version.

A similar thing happened to me after upgrading to UBUNTU 19.10. The pixel saver extension was incompatible with the new version of gnome and was breaking the interface. Application menu was empty and the top bar menus was not working as expected.

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog 
Dec 12 17:07:44 nb001 gnome-shell[1649]: JS ERROR: Exception in callback for signal: hidden: TypeError: global.screen is undefined#012getWindow@/home/lucas/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/pixel-saver@deadalnix.me/util.js:9:1#012updateVisibility@/home/lucas/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/pixel-saver@deadalnix.me/buttons.js:209:13#012_emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27#012_hideDone@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:619:9#012_callOnFunction@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:208:13#012_updateTweenByIndex@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:342:9#012_updateTweens@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:355:18#012_onEnterFrame@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/tweener/tweener.js:370:10#012_emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27#012_onNewFrame@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:238:9#012ClutterFrameTicker</<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/tweener.js:209:13
```

If this is happening, I suggest:

1. Login with gnome. On the login screen click on the gear before typing your password, select gnome, and proceed with the login and wait the desktop to load.
2. Press ALT+F2 to show the command popup, type the `gnome-terminal` and enter.
3. On the terminal type the command `tail -f /var/log/syslog &` and enter.
4. Try to access the application menu and see if a similar "JS ERROR" appears on your terminal and your recognize a **.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions** on the error line.
5. If is the case, type: rm -R ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*
6. Press ALT+F2 to show the command popup, type `r` and enter.

If you problem is with the "pixel saver" extension, a very good alternative is the extension [unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/).

Answer (score 0):

Click "Filter results" and choose "All" for both "Type" and "Sources".